# ¿Como puedo filtrar y mostrar solo la hora de un datetime?

Tags: javascript

Realizo un filtrado, en base a eso me muestra datos en una tabla, y en un campo` me muestra fecha y hora y solo necesito que me muestre la hora.

```
 success: function(cntxAjax){
        table.clear().draw()
        cntxAjax.cntxMoventMilk.forEach(function(moventmilk){
            table.row.add({
                '0':moventmilk.ExpirationDateTime,
                '1':moventmilk.DateTimeMovement,
                '2':moventmilk.Litters,
                '3':moventmilk.MilkTemperature, 
                '4':moventmilk.Acidity,                   
                '5':moventmilk.Dencity,
                '6':moventmilk.ProviderID,
                '7':moventmilk.Analist,
            }).node().id = moventmilk.id;
            table.draw(true);
        });
```

Comment: Que tiene que ver tu codigo con tu pregunta, no le veo relacion

Comment: En la fila número '1' de mi tabla, es donde tiene que mostrar solo la hora, lo cual  me muestra la fecha y la hora  @Miguel Zarate

Comment: entonces movementmilk.ExpirationDateTime si este es un objeto tipo Data solo agrega ExpirationDateTime.d.getHours(); y obtienes la hora

Comment: Como estás manejando al escribir en la tabla. ¿Tienes configurado tus data de las celdas?¿o lo haces por medio de los target, index, de ellas?

Comment: Soy nueva en esto, disculpame pero no logro entenderte.  @Aaron Romero

Comment: Veo que tu tabla usa la Api de Datatable.js. Pregunto por la configuración inicial de la tabla.

Comment: Si, asi es utilizo  la Api de Datatable.js

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [tu propio formato con la función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString) `ExpirationDateTime.toLocaleString();`

```js
var time = new Date();
console.log(
  time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
);
```